# How to make https server on sockets

Tags: python, sockets, ssl, https

I am trying to make a web server on sockets in python. I saw how to make https support for server from module http.server in python by wrapping its socket with a .pem certificate. I would like to make https support on my socket server. I have a self-signed certificate for a localhost and it worked for a ready-made server, but my server has an error:

```
Traceback(most recent call last):
  File "webserver.py", line 84, in main
    server.start_server()
  File "C:\b\nw\12t\http_lite.py", line 103, in start_server
    conn, addr = ssock.accept()
  File "C:\Python37\lib\ssl.py", line 1188, in accept
    server_side=True)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\ssl.py", line 423, in wrap_socket
    session = session
  File "C:\Python37\lib\ssl.py", line 870, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Python37\lib\ssl.py", line 1139, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_CERTIFICATE_UNKNOWN] sslv3 alert certificate unknown (_ssl.c: 1076)
```

And also if I allow to open a site in a browser:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "webserver.py", line 84, in main
    server.start_server()
  File "C:\b\nw\12t\http_lite.py", line 100, in start_server
    conn, addr = ssock.accept()
  File "C:\Python37\lib\ssl.py", line 1188, in accept
    server_side=True)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\ssl.py", line 423, in wrap_socket
    session = session
  File "C:\Python37\lib\ssl.py", line 870, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Python37\lib\ssl.py", line 1139, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
OSError: [Errno 0] Error
```

My connection setup code looks like this:

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
s.bind ((self.host, self.port))
s.listen(self.backlog)
ssock = ssl.wrap_socket(s,
                        server_side=True,
                        certfile='localhost.pem',
                        ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)
in the while loop
conn, addr = ssock.accept()
....
```

Please help me figure out what I am doing wrong.
Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: i would not do this ... it is probably better to put nginx in front of your socket and let nginx to all the ssl type stuff

Comment: @JoranBeasley I agree, but I would like to do this on raw sockets